# ProgressBar in Notification [ANDROID]

Tags: java, android, multithreading, notifications

I know that there are many topic about it. I know that there is the android developer website and even if i use the code from this website i have an error.

i just want to put a ProgressBar in the Notification.
SO i call this method that i took from Android Developer website :

```
public static void generateNotification(Context context){   

    final NotificationManager mNotifyManager =(NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(context);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Picture Download")
            .setContentText("Download in progress");
    // Start a lengthy operation in a background thread
    new Thread(
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int incr;

                for (incr = 0; incr <= 100; incr+=5) {

                        mBuilder.setProgress(100, incr, false);                        
                        mNotifyManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

                            try {

                                Thread.sleep(5*1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                Log.d("Generate Notif", "sleep failure");
                            }
                }
                // When the loop is finished, updates the notification
                mBuilder.setContentText("Download complete")
                .setProgress(0,0,false);
                mNotifyManager.notify(100, mBuilder.build());
            }
        }
    // Starts the thread by calling the run() method in its Runnable
    ).start();
}
```

and i have this error :

```
10-01 15:37:42.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9840): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1250
10-01 15:37:42.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9840): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.Notification$Builder.build
10-01 15:37:42.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9840): at com.Tools.UtilClass$10.run(UtilClass.java:813)
10-01 15:37:42.226: E/AndroidRuntime(9840): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

and this :

```
E/WindowManager(9840): Activity com.main.LoginConnection has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@410c2238 that was originally added here
E/WindowManager(9840): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.main.LoginConnection has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@410c2238 that was originally added here
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at com.main.LoginConnection.getRegisterId(LoginConnection.java:281)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at com.main.LoginConnection.onCreate(LoginConnection.java:101)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/WindowManager(9840): Activity com.main.LoginConnection has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41162188 that was originally added here
E/WindowManager(9840): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.main.LoginConnection has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41162188 that was originally added here
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at com.Tools.UtilClass.openSettingApp(UtilClass.java:557)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at com.Tools.UtilClass$4.onClick(UtilClass.java:383)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/WindowManager(9840):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

so i don't understand and why i have this error...

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest using `NotificationCompat.Builder`, rather than just `Notification.Builder` - that may be the first issue you're running into (are you ignoring warnings?). You'll need the app compat v7 and support v4 libraries.

Secondly, you're not going to see a notification. Notifications need the following to actually post:

1. Content Title
2. Content Text
3. Content Intent
4. Small icon

To see your notification, add a content Intent `setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT))` and a small icon `setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_notification_clear_all` - then you'll be able to post it.

By making those modifications, your code works for me. You have some other issues, notably that your download notification is not removed when you're done, but that's as simple as changing your `notify(100` call to `notify(0`, the number you're passing there is the notification id, so they need to match if it's supposed to replace the progress one.

I've not fixed your memory leak, that's a matter of not hanging onto the activity context within your thread.

Comment: I pet the NOtificationCompat.Builder but if i put this code, i have the error 'this method is undefined...' on the setProgress method.. so how can i do whereas i took this code on the ANdroid Developer website

Comment: i find the problem. it was because i had the android-support-v13 and 
apparently i should to use the android-support-V4. BUt for this moment nothing happens..

Comment: As I said, you need to use NotificationCompat.Builder, and you need the 4 things I mentioned in order for the notification to post. If you don't have all 4, it will not post.